# Sort data with linux shell

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I try to sort data

```
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
```

to get 3 items per line and separate by `,`.
as usual ,i will use `split --line=3` after that sort with `paste -s x* -d',' >result` ,any shorter way to achieve my goal . 
The result:

```
aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sample data is terrible, can you update it? Otherwise, no one understands your question.

Here I try to guess your request:

```
sort file |paste - - -  -d,
```

for 100 per line

```
sort file |xargs -n100 |sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Comment: but i need separate them by `,` ,like the result above

Comment: thanks and sorry for the data ,but i wonder if item per line is 100 ,will i still use `paste (-)X100 -d,`

Comment: if you prefer the simple command, try xargs. Otherwise, you can try awk to put all in one-liner.